# Alan Grant's intelligent velociraptors

Tags: evolution, intelligence, dinosaurs, anatomy

In the third edition of Jurassic Park film Alan Grant before meeting the Kirbys gives a speech in which he says

> ......If it were not for the cataclysmic event that overtook them it would have been raptors rather than humans who would have been the dominant species on the planet.

So if it really wouldn't have been for the cataclysmic event that overtook them and raptors somehow became the dominant species on the planet how different would they look from what they originally were portrayed as in the film and what extra characteristics will they acquire and what else will they let go off

Comment: Clever girls.....

Comment: i hope you know that IRL raptors was nothing like in the movie, right? Much smaller, feathers, so on.

Comment: As with most questions that come from the premise of "How does this creature evolve over the next X million years," there is really no singular path forward. There are potentially infinite equally valid answers, because evolution isn't an intelligent process working towards a final goal. For your world, feel free to come up with whatever adaptations you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless they developed prehensile thumbs, there is little chance of them becoming the dominant species like humans.

That gives us two possible outcomes:

1. They don't develop prehensile thumbs, thus are unable to develop tools. They remain one predator among several, but due to their intelligence and pack hunting, dominate their territory until food runs out and they die off. No tools, so they don't learn to preserve food or improve their advantages.
2. They develop prehensile thumbs, and eventually start making tools. They improve their chances by using spears and rocks to bring down prey at less risk. Even if they lose, most of them are far enough away that the hunting party can try again later, instead of up close where they can get killed by an angry T-rex.
   Due to their habit of using tools, their upper body and forearms develop a wider range of motion. Similarly, the tail, which acted as a balancing counterweight for running, now limits the force the upper body can exert: it starts getting smaller, and either ends up as a vestigial or very light and prehensile. The feathers change, disappearing from the lower body to reduce the potential for parasites, since they now live in crowded caves and mud/wooden houses.
   If their diet evolves to including fruit, in case meat is unavailable, their faces will shorten and their teeth will change to accommodate the changes in diet.
   Essentially, they'll look a lot like feathered humans. We're products of our environment too.